# session data empty on the payment gateway return URL in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

There are several questions on this issue and I have tried most of the solutions suggested there, still I am unable to figure out the issue. I am using PayU payment API. Upon successful payment, the session data is empty on the RETURN URL. I had set only few fields in the session like user ID, product IDs in the cart

Below is the return URL function:

```
public function payment_success() {
    echo "<pre>"; print_r($_SESSION);
    exit;
}
```

The output I see:

```
    Array
(
    [__ci_last_regenerate] => 1600755715
)
```

Note that the session data persists while redirecting from function to function. Issue is only on the payment gateway's return URL function which is also in the same controller

PHP Version:7.2.31
Codeigniter Version:3.1.11

//My config.php:

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 0;
$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

Possibilities I have tried as suggested

```
//1
$config['sess_save_path'] = APPPATH.'ci_session/';

//2
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;

//3 in Session.php
// ini_set('session.name', $params['cookie_name']);
ini_set('session.id', $params['cookie_name']);

//4 tried under PHP versions 7.1 and 7.3
```

Comment: Check if your session cookie is set with the `SameSite` attribute, and if so, which value. It would have to be `Lax` at most, `Strict` causes this exact problem.

Comment: I have not configured SameSite. How/where to set it?

Comment: Check whether that’s actually the case first, use your browser dev tools.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was about "cookie SameSite attribute". It is coming for Chrome version 84. Thanks to @04FS for the hint. Adding the below line in .htaccess worked for me

```
Header always edit Set-Cookie (.*) "$1; SameSite=None;Secure"
```